# detect a click and drop on a line in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have converted line to movieclip. Now I want to detect click and drag on line not on whole movieclip how to add listener just to the line ?

Simple question and nobody knows ? On Google I can't find one single article just to do that.

Comment: Describe better your problem. AS2 or AS3? Your line is inside what, or what is inside you line movieclip? Add a sample of the code. If you have nothing coded yet, try do something and, if you stuck on something, put it in your question.

Comment: AS3 of course. Nothing in movie clip except the line. There's no sample code since I don't have idea of how to do it :(

Comment: is this what you want to do? http://wonderfl.net/c/bZNj

Answer (score 0):

man , a line is nothing but a piece of stroke.
if you convert it as a movieClip , u can add event for that clip. but for the line inside the clip alone , how can you add an event? to me its not possible , if you got a solution please do post in here . . .